# sejda-console creates the --output file as hidden attribute

Tags: windows, command-line, pdf-generation, sejda

I'm using the merge command of sejda-console 3.1 version for Windows in Win-7 command line window.  Like this:

```
> sejda-console merge -f D:\PDF_INPUT\1.pdf D:\PDF_INPUT\2.pdf -o D:\PDF_OUTPUT\merged_file.pdf
```

The output file `merged_file.pdf`is created but as hidden attribute.

However, in Linux it works fine.

Why?  Can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an issue and has been fixed, just upgrade to a more recent version, 3.1.2 or higher

Comment: @andravacondio Thanks!